# Where this function is defined?

Tags: esp8266

This is the code for timer example in esp8266..(got from a website)

My doubt is where the function   timer1_enable(TIM_DIV16, TIM_EDGE, TIM_SINGLE)  is defined ??
I am look in Ticker.cpp, but not found.

```cpp
#include < ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include < Ticker.h >

Ticker blinker;

#define LED 2  //On board LED

//=======================================================================
void ICACHE_RAM_ATTR onTimerISR(){
    digitalWrite(LED,!(digitalRead(LED)));  //Toggle LED Pin
    timer1_write(600000);//12us
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("");

    pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);

    //Initialize Ticker every 0.5s
    timer1_attachInterrupt(onTimerISR);
    timer1_enable(TIM_DIV16, TIM_EDGE, TIM_SINGLE);
    timer1_write(600000); //120000 us
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Comment: Found your example code [here](https://circuits4you.com/2018/01/02/esp8266-timer-ticker-example/). Please always provide a link, when you ask questions about a code from the web.

Comment: Also note that in C++, trivial functions are sometimes fully implemented in the .h file, so a search of the .cpp file might not reveal any code. This is especially common for access functions ("setters" and "getters"), where a function definition takes no more space (or very little more) than a declaration would.

Answer (score 2):

Those functions have nothing to do with the Ticker library. Those functions are defined in the [ESP8266 core](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_timer.cpp).

The example you cite has this at the top of it:

> Hardware Timer0 is used by WiFi Functions. We can use only Timer1. **Use of timer instead of Ticker** gives advantage of precision timing and You can get timer interrupt in micro seconds.

Note the use of "instead of Ticker" there. That says that the code below has nothing to do with Ticker.